# WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd + 404 not found…

Tags: http-status-code-404, asp.net

I got my `asp.net web application to run on a shared hosting`.... When i inspected through `firebug` i found `WebResource.axd` and `ScriptResource.axd` returned 404 not found....

`WebResource.axd?d=rpqvYNSuvgzlFHiQAGNqVg2&t=633861392532362500` - `404 not found`

`ScriptResource.axd?d=QH2WS5PI-hjjDYgFwsGU2R-Ze_5jnx-rARAoYxg3JBJyMBl78kd2glg_Q2erkzpacmOcEqLLKqaqHoUVJifLezkXnAGUAWVurxXH feAY8yI1&t=ffffffff873865f3` - `404 not found`

Then i searched in stackoverflow and found this link,

[ASP.NET web application - WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd files - Loading time issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433512/asp-net-web-application-webresource-axd-and-scriptresource-axd-files-loading)

It didnt help me... I am on shared hosting... I use asp.net 3.5 sp1 and sqlserver2005..

`I dont use any ajax libraries...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a.aspx) was deactived globally. You could try to add this to the httpHandler section of your web.config and see what happens:

```
<add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="true"/>
```

Comment: @splattne ok i ll try it...

Answer (score -1):

Plesk Admins,
Please disable the Web Application Firewall to solve this issue.

`Tools & Settings > Web Application Firewall > Turn Off`

Cheers!